# Jquery POST doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

I have a function made in javascript, using jQuery. I use this to send some info to the server

```
function cart(val, theImg)
{
    var url = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+'/';
    if(!theImg.hasClass('added'))
    {
        jQuery.post(url,{ajax:'1',compedit:'shopping-cart',q:'1',tocart:val},function(result){
            theImg.attr({'src':'/media/images/substract_from_cart.png','title':'Substract from cart','alt':'Substract from cart'}).addClass('added');
            jQuery('.btip').text('Substract From Cart');                 
        }, 'text');
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery.post(url,{'ajax':'1','compedit':'shopping-cart','q':'0','tocart':val},function(result){
            theImg.attr({'src':'/media/images/add_to_cart.png','title':'Add To Cart','alt':'Add To Cart'}).removeClass('added');
            jQuery('.btip').text('Add To Cart');                 
        }, 'text');
    }
}
```

My problem is, that this function does not send the data to the server in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari)!
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: any error in console ? can u debug in firebug

Comment: Are u sure you're running the page from some server (i.e. `http://localhost/...`) or from the filesystem (i.e. `file:///...`)??

Comment: Does it work in any other browser?

Comment: Your code is inconsistent. In one `jQuery.post` you surround ajax, compedit and stuff with quotes, in the other you don't.

Comment: @Ravi: There is no error in the console.

Comment: @Juri: I run this from its webserver.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: it was consistent, but I tryed so many ways, I forgot them as you se now.
I used it on the first place as you see it in the first jQuery.post 
It works in Firefox but doesn't in webkit.

Comment: Then doesn't webkit have some kind of error console, like Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first `post` isn't right add `'`:

```
 jQuery.post(url,{'ajax':'1','compedit':'shopping-cart','q':'1','tocart':val}..
```

Comment: @mgraph, no, the console is empty.

Comment: @mgraph the variables are not sent to the server.

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['tocart']))
{
 $q=$_POST['q'];
 $v=array();
 $db->q("SELECT * FROM artworks WHERE file='".cleanQuery($_POST['tocart'])."'", 1);
 $v=$db->rows;
 $cart->update_cart($v['id'],$q,$v['currency'],$v['price']);
 echo 1;
}`

Comment: @mgraph yes, on client side I alerted the tocart value. 

Anyway, the script it works in Firefox